# pass caption to custom command listing

Tags: listings

I have a command `\customfile` that creates a listing with the file passed as an argument.

```tex
\newcommand{\customfile}[1]{
  \lstinputlisting[language=customlanguage,%
    frame=lines,xleftmargin=8pt,xrightmargin=8pt,columns=fixed]{#1}
}
```

Now I'd like to change this command such that I can (optionally) pass a caption to it.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get an optional argument, well, add an optional argument ...

```
\newcommand{\customfile}[2][]{
  \lstinputlisting[language=python,%
    frame=lines,xleftmargin=8pt,xrightmargin=8pt,columns=fixed,caption=#1]{#2}
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{sample.py}
printf("Hello!\n");
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{listings}
\newcommand{\customfile}[2][]{
  \lstinputlisting[language=python,%
    frame=lines,xleftmargin=8pt,xrightmargin=8pt,columns=fixed,caption=#1]{#2}
}
\begin{document}
\customfile{sample.py}

\customfile[Now with caption]{sample.py}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Pretty new to this and tried it with the reversed argument order (which didn't work)...